# Uncaught Reference Error: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

i am using an ajax function to read some contents. Also i want to impliment lazy loading in this content

my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var getparam = '<?php echo $this->paramData;?>';
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Index/" + getparam
   }).done(function (data) {
     console.log(data);
     $('#append_here').html(data);
     var check = 0;
     var int = 0;
     var int = setInterval("doThis(check)", 10);

     function doThis(check) {
       var images = $('img:hidden').length;
       if(check >= images) {
         clearInterval(int);
       }
       $('img:hidden').eq(0).fadeIn(10);
       check++;
     }
   });
 });
```

the content coming perfectly. after that there is an error present that doThis is not defind

if any one know about this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval("doThis(check)", 10);
```

This calls `doThis` from the global scope since it's called thru an eval-like fashion - and `doThis` isn't in the global scope.

Try this instead:

```
var int = setInterval(function(){
   var images = $('img:hidden').length;
   if(check >= images) clearInterval(int);
   $('img:hidden').eq(0).fadeIn(10);
   check++;
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put doThis() in the global scope, not inside $(document).ready() or inner functions/ callbacks of that.

To say it simply:-  move it below the end of the `$(document).ready( ...)` section.

This kind of error is not entirely uncommon, now that with jQuery we write so much of the Javascript inside the $(document).ready() callback.

Comment: Don't forget to move `var check` also to the global scope. Otherwise the counter won't increment actually.